# iOS 8 - How to register an app to be included in the system share menu?

Tags: ios, iphone, share

The dialog below comes up if you share an image from the *Photos* app on iOS 8 devices.
How to get an app into the *red circled* share menu?
(I would like to register an iOS 8 iPhone app for the extensions .png, .jpg and .gif) 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an app extension.

According to Apple:

> To add a new target to your Xcode app project, choose File > New >
>   Target. In the sidebar on the left side of the new target dialog,
>   choose Application Extension for iOS or OS X. In the pane on the right
>   side of the dialog, Xcode displays the templates you can choose.

You'll want to choose an Action extension

Comment: I'm using Air on Windows, so I don't have access to XCode. Can you please post a template for an image (png, jpg, gif) action extension?