# Calling the system share menu on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8.3

I'm trying to figure out how to programatically show the system share menu, but all info I can find is [how to register an app to said menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388753/ios-8-how-to-register-an-app-to-be-included-in-the-system-share-menu).

How can I call the dialog programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of UIActivityViewController, here's a quick example

```
let objectsToShare = ["a string"]
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: objectsToShare,
        applicationActivities: nil)

    // if your app can run on an iPad, this menu
    // will present as a pop over controller
    // and as such, needs to be configured
    // consider the bar button item property
    // if needed

    // should be the rect that the pop over should anchor to
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any

    // present the controller
    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How can I check if is presented as popover?

Comment: I have added a quick example with required properties to my answer